# Online version of Android Studio 4

Tags: android, android-studio

My nephew wants to learn android development, he only has a chromebook that his school gave which restricts him to install anything. So checking if there's a browser based online version of Android Studio (4 preferably) where he can write code, execute wihtout installing locally. thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ideal for him would be to:

1. buy his own machine
2. connect to existing machines at his home or relatives using teamviewer (or any other remote access software)
3. buy a VPS and setup android studio on it, then connect using remote access software as in step 2 to use it. (google provides 1 year free vps for up to 300$ at [cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com) or he can also use azure by microsoft student discount)

I hope it helps.